# prove this proposition is valid using the algebraic proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Prove that tho proposition is valid using algebra

### $$p \rightarrow q
$$

### $$q\rightarrow r$$

---

### $$\therefore \lnot p\lor r$$

what i've tried is

$\bigl((p\rightarrow q)\land(q\rightarrow r)\bigr)\rightarrow \lnot p\lor r$

$\lnot\bigl((\lnot p\lor q)\land(\lnot q\lor r)\bigr)\lor (\lnot p\lor r)$

and now im stuck

Comment: "using algebra" ???

Comment: See [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) and [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Propositional_logic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA algebraic proposition

Comment: @YourongZang how can you just assume $r = p$?

Comment: @ClementYung You're right. I have deleted my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(p \to q) \wedge (q \to r) \rightarrow (p \to r) &\Leftrightarrow (\lnot p \vee q) \wedge (\lnot q \vee r) \to (\lnot p \vee r) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \lnot((\lnot p \vee q) \wedge (\lnot q \vee r)) \vee (\lnot p \vee r) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (q \wedge \lnot r) \vee \lnot p \vee r \\
&\Leftrightarrow (p \wedge \lnot q) \vee \lnot p \vee (q \wedge \lnot r) \vee r \\
&\Leftrightarrow ((p \vee \lnot p) \wedge (\lnot q \vee \lnot p)) \vee ((q \vee r) \wedge (\lnot r \vee r)) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \lnot q \vee \lnot p \vee q \vee r \\
&\Leftrightarrow \text{Tautology as $q \vee \lnot q$} 
\end{align*}

Comment: how can u get from the second row to the third row ?

Comment: It is clearly wrong : $(p→q) ∧ (q→r)$ is **not** equivalent to $\lnot p \lor r$.

Comment: @MaxBrian I've edited my answer. Please see if you understand.